# Why do universities fund Ph.D. students in the sciences?

Tags: phd, funding, salary, politics

I was recently accepted into an applied math Ph.D. here in the U.S., and being the 1st in my family to graduate from university, I had a hard time explaining to them why my university will be spending close to 50k on me per year (stipend, tuition, health insurance, fees).

I know that I will be working for the university as a TA, and that perhaps that will go towards covering some of the costs outlined previously, however, it hardly seems to justify the full expenditure.

Comment: What makes you think you won't be earning your keep as a TA?

Comment: @BrianBorchers because I was previously employed at my undergrad institution as a tutor, doing similar work to that which I will be performing at my current university (grading, recitations, etc.) and the numbers of hours + pay does not come close to the amount cited in my question.

Comment: It is not that you will be overpaid as a grad student.  It is that you were extremely underpaid as an undergrad tutor.  Actually, you will probably still be underpaid.  If they hired Ph.D. holders to do your TA work, it would cost them a lot more.

Comment: The tuition part of the story is basically irrelevant. To my understanding, the university does their accounting in the particular way that they do it because it helps them with their taxes, but to a student, PhD student tuition in STEM simply doesn't exist.

Comment: There are three kinds of useful activities: 1) those that keep us alive and healthy; 2) those that we find inherently interesting; and 3) those that help us do 1 or 2. The university invests in you, because it expects that you will eventually do 2 or 3.

Comment: I am not an expert on this, so please correct me if I am wrong.  But to my understanding, the university is probably not funding OP.  The federal government is funding OP.  The university is just where the paperwork originates and the money gets spent.

Comment: Why is the federal government funding OP? I would rather live in a society with a surplus rather than a deficit of smart people.  University is a warehouse for the smart people that we don't currently have a use for.

Comment: Note that Universities also "fund" Ph.D. students in the liberal arts and humanities - for mostly the same reasons.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I understand that Ph.D. students in the humanities/liberal arts don't get nearly enough support as candidates in STEM disciplines. It seems to me that if the whole "TA-ing pays your way" rationale is to hold water, then support ought to be equal across all disciplines. There are articles citing Ph.D. students in non STEM fields graduating with substantial debt vs. no debt from their science counterparts.

Comment: @JohnWayne360 I agree that non-STEM Ph.D. students are getting less and/or not enough support, and being hooded with debt (along with a hood). But they are getting support.

Comment: In some countries PhD candidates are simply employees. You will not be a "student" in the same way than undergrad students are, you will be doing real work (not only teaching, but also research).

Comment: For reference, you can see the percent of U.S. PhDs funded primarily by various sources (TA, RA, fellowship, self funded), divided by broad field in [this PDF](http://nsf.gov/statistics/2016/nsf16300/data/tab35.pdf). Note that TA as primary source of support is actually more common in humanities than STEM fields. RA funding is much less common in humanities, which makes sense given the limited grant funding in those fields.

Comment: I would probably consider doing a PhD an "apprenticeship in research", for which you of course need to get paid. And you get paid a bit more (although still far too little IMO) than other apprentices, because you already have a relevant degree, i.e. education/experience.

Comment: @BrianBorchers: There are quite a few universities which have more PhD candidates than are needed for teaching duties, or alternatively, they all teach but very little.

Comment: Note that it's perfectly possible for a PhD student to NOT be funded by the university.  So think of it as you (and every other student) paying the same tuition & fees.  Then some students, because they have useful skills, may get jobs at the university - TA, RA, &c - that include some of those costs as part of the pay.  Others may get jobs elsewhere that let them pay the costs, or have rich parents, trust funds, or (in a couple of cases I know of) have made a few million in startups.

Comment: @Ian The tuition part is very much relevant for the professor's side of the equation.  It may well make the PhD student nearly as expensive as a post-doc (I pay only about 50% more direct/indirect costs for a 55k/yr post-doc.)   Tuition is charged because students take classes which have to be paid for, and for RA's that can come from grant money.  For the TA case, of course the university pays itself, but even there you're charging undergraduate programs (maybe state-subsidized) and paying for graduate teaching.  Large organizations are complex beasts.

Comment: @JohnWayne360: When I had similar conversations with some relatives, I found it simpler just to say I had a full scholarship to cover tuition and living expenses, rather than trying to explain the principles behind who gets funded and how/why.  That's not the word that's usually used, but "scholarship" is not so different from "fellowship", and it gives the right idea (namely, that through a competitive process you were selected to have your education paid for; this is true even if that process was part of graduate admission).  Then it's a familiar concept, rather than strange and different.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

A good question. Why would the school make this investment (which could be closer to $100K/year)?

1. As pointed out, if you are TAing/grading/teaching, you are providing services that the school charges undergraduates for.
2. The funding of a university is not entirely like that of a business. Some of the money is a direct investment in purely academic pursuits, especially that from grants. Educating people and doing basic research is part of what that money is allocated for.
3. Averaged over all the graduate students, the direct value that they provide to the university in terms of research which goes on to get grants/prestige/donations/patents is substantial.
4. There is a non-trivial chance that you will become a wealthy donor to the school.

Comment: I think it also should be emphasized that most universities *want you to have enough money to focus on your work for them.* If they pay too little, you may be inclined, or even forced, to supplement their money with another job, which will distract you, tire you, and demand your time, none of which the university wants. Ultimately, PhD work tends to require a very substantial portion of one’s time and attention, which one cannot offer if one also has to worry about food and shelter. So if they want the work done, they need to pay enough to the people doing it that they can focus.

Comment: @KRyan GF is in the situation above, funding ran out, needing to work odd jobs while finishing up her thesis.  All I can say about that is it seems borderline impossible to me, and she's really struggling with it.

Comment: For most US PhD programs in math, I think 3 (excepting perhaps "prestige") and 4 are nearly inconsequential.  Most math departments bring in relatively little money from grants.  It is nearly impossible to get an RA position in math unlike in science or engineering.  Grad students are paid solely for their teaching/grading duties, because this is a crucial service to the math dept.

Comment: Also, many businesses support general research, like academia.

Comment: I don't think this should be the answer. It misses a very important caveat: why don't these reasons apply to non-STEM PhD students, at least enough to have similar funding?

Comment: @gwg I alluded to this in a comment for my question. Still, I think this is a good answer.

Comment: Rather than disagree here, I wrote the answer I wanted. :)

Comment: @KRyan I even heard a professor stating that they pay _just enough_ so you don't have to worry about food and shelter, but no more so you don't get distracted.

Comment: @gwg  Competition.  From industry.  Treat a non-STEM PhD student like **** and they'll look around, see that real-world jobs would be nicer, but not so much nicer that it's worth jumping ship from the research they love.  Industry treats STEM people much nicer, so the threshold needed to stop them from jumping is higher.

Comment: @Joel This exactly.  Good professors doing good research need good PhD students.  Good students cost money.  Good research builds prestige.  Prestige rakes in undergrads.  Prestige wins funding grants.  Prestige makes a university money.  Gotta spend money to make money - this is a constant in the universe.

Comment: @Joel: While there is industry competition, a candidate looking to make a decent living first and foremost will always end up with the industry job.  PhD stipends are sufficient to pay rent and buy cheap food.  That's it.

Comment: 5. It probably costs them nothing. A grant is likely paying for you. (Other bullets allude to this, but I thought I'd state it explicitly)

Answer (score 54):

**Universities don't "fund" Ph.D. candidates. They pay them *salaries*** - or what should be recognized as salaries - to do research. In more normal states (such as the Netherlands), nobody is trying to deny this fact, and PhD candidates are formally in a employer-employee legal relation with their university. In other states (such as the US, or rather individual states within the federation) there are on-again-off-again legal struggles regarding this question.

As an example, look for the US NLRB decisions 332-111 (October 31st, 2000, NYU) and later decision 342-42 (July 13 2004, Brown U) **edit:** and the recent and *excellent* [364-90](https://www.aaup.org/brief/columbia-university-364-nlrb-no-90-august-23-2016) (August 23 2016, Columbia U).

By the way, even employment in teaching isn't always recognized, and occasionally (again, in the US specifically, but less so in recent years) universities try to pass off the teaching work as training/learning experience and not pay PhD candidates for it.

Now, of course it's not quite that simple: The relation of a PhD candidate and his/her university is not entirely the same as that of the line worker and the factory, or the typist and office etc. When you're in a PhD program you are still learning and acquiring skills; however, unlike an undergraduate student, you do this mostly by carrying out actual research work (and perhaps also teaching work). These two types of activity are what a university is supposed carry out, so you are significantly contributing to realizing the university's (ongoing) objectives. A PhD candidate is a trained professional in his general field already when s/he is inducted, and s/he gradually acquires expertise, hones skills, and trains in the research aspect of his/her discipline, as opposed to other applicative aspects of it.

Comment: It is obvious that many (but not all) PhD students are in fact employees of their university.  To say that the university funds those students does not imply otherwise any more than saying Congress funds the army implies soldiers are unpaid volunteers.

Comment: @emory: Well, you wouldn't say "the supermarket funds the cashiers", right?

Comment: +1. To me the question and most of the answers are weirdly US-centric. Universities are in the business of doing research. As PhD-Student you are doing the scientific work and get (under-)paid for it. Scientific projects are funded because they contribute to society (in terms of knowledge, technological progress, etc). The idea that universities "fund" students, because they might later donate is completely absurd to me.

Comment: @emory: So, again, WalMart doesn't fund cashiers, it funds cashier positions. Your university doesn't "fund you", it funds your position. It _pays_ you a salary, or a salary disguised as a stiped/scholarship.

Comment: @emory: Also, one you switch to the WalMart examples, OP wouldn't ask "Why does WalMart fund cashiers?" - they do work for WalMart, so it pays them / funds positions which they fill.

Comment: Much better answer than the accepted one. They pay you money because you work for them, simple as that. The company/university receives money for teaching and researching, so they hire people to do teaching and researching for them. Then the accountants, lawmakers and marketing come in and try to make it look complicated, which it isn't.

Comment: @BlindKungFuMaster "To me the question and most of the answers are weirdly US-centric" -  Like most mildly to highly social SE sites, unfortunately. Most internet, even.

Comment: I wouldn't say that the answers and questions are "weirdly" U.S.-centric, as the question specifies the country. But, I completely agree that outside of the U.S., for example in Europe, PhD students much more likely to be directly funded in the context of a specific project.

Answer (score 47):

I think another point worth considering is that two of the costs you list this as covering, tuition and fees, go back to the university. So while they might technically be losing money on paper by giving you these things, you could see it more as a form of creative accounting. They are not actually *losing* it, but rather not *making* it.

Depending on the university and how they operate, they might expect to regain more of the money you are given in your stipend via other means (housing, food, parking, etc.).

Once you account for the difference between on-paper spending on you and how much you are actually getting in real money, you can start explaining the rest of it as the fact you are in fact doing work for the university. Working as a TA, doing research, and other tasks involved in the Ph.D process.

It's worth considering that Ph.D students are in the same job market as other bachelors / masters holders, and that the university needs to compete with the non-academic market to an extent. Depending on the field, you might be foregoing a substantial salary by obtaining a Ph.D. Not everyone is necessarily going to be willing to do that, so offering a lot of freebies can encourage people who might go straight to business to remain in academia, at least briefly.

As such, it's probably more helpful to view this money as a combination of discounts and payment for TA/research work. Trying to build favor with you should you become a successful researcher no doubt plays a part as well.

Comment: "They are not actually losing it, but rather not making it."  On top of that - they wouldn't be making that money.  If they stopped paying and started charging tuition, they'd end up with unfilled positions.

Answer (score 17):

I don't think the accepted answer really addresses the question and want to put forward my own opinion. STEM PhDs are funded for a few reasons:

- **Military:** Investment in STEM fields is an investment in technology that the military wants. Think about how much R&D came out of the Manhattan Project, the Space Race, Cryptanalysis of the Enigma, etc.
- **Health care:** cancer, Ebola, Zika, etc. are important problems that society agrees need to be solved. At least in the US, the NIH invests heavily in biomedical research, and many fields try to align themselves with this funding, e.g. a computer scientist or mathematician turned computational biologist.
- **Tech companies:** Most major universities now have entrepreneurship-support programs, and no one wants to miss out on the next Google.

Compare this to someone getting their PhD in theology. I am not arguing that their work does not have *social value*, but I think we can safely say that society at large is not willing to invest as much—if any—money.

Fair or not and right or wrong, I think this is why STEM PhDs are funded: **we want the innovative technology that is built on top of basic scientific research.*** In lieu of this, I'd argue that PhD students are pretty cheap labor.

* *I think an interesting question is why do STEM fields have such immense practical value? [Thomas Kuhn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Structure_of_Scientific_Revolutions) and [Eugene Wigner](https://www.dartmouth.edu/~matc/MathDrama/reading/Wigner.html) both address this topic. My favorite answer is one that I think is fairly parsimonious: Scientific fields are practical because if a field is practical, we call science.*

Comment: Well, what about fundamental theoretical research in STEM? Specifically, what about Math? Also, your answer regards external sources of funding - specific government or corporate sector funded projects; but universities pay PhD candidates in many disciplines even without project-specific funding.

Comment: @einpoklum, many theoretical results have important practical applications, and society understands this to varying degree. I think even laymen have the sense that stuff like quantum physics trickles down into stuff like quantum computing—this probably wasn't the case before WWII. Of course, we do not always agree on what is worth funding, which is why part of a scientist's job—like it or not—is to sell their work. [Don't take it for me](https://www.cs.virginia.edu/~robins/YouAndYourResearch.html).

Comment: To answer your second question, many universities do pay PhD candidates, and I think other answers offer reasons why this may be. But my argument is that _the primary reason basic research is funded is because society wants the resultant technology_. Everything else, e.g. cheap teachers for freshman-level courses, is icing on the cake.

Comment: Ok, I guess you earned your +1.

Comment: I think this answer requires a few logical leaps—arguably intuitive leaps, but an answer should be explicit. What is the link between government/industry interest, and university pay? This answer makes no sense unless there is one, so at the very least such a link should be posited (and, ideally, demonstrated).

Comment: @KRyan: True. Basic research is typically funded by the government, through various grant agencies, though the money goes through the university.

Answer (score 10):

Because you will be a source of **incredibly** cheap highly skilled labor. This is especially the case if your field involves lab work.

As an example, I was a statistician at a major research institute shortly after graduating. This institute included graduate students. When any of the research cores needed my help, they were (internally) billed $160/hour. Alternatively, the PI's could try to get their graduate students to do the work instead. Of course, there's no direct bill involved in asking a graduate student to do your work, but you do have to fund their $50k a year. If they were to work 40 hours a week, this would amount to $25/hr...except I would guess that most of them averaged 50 hours a week (at least). And then some of the students were funded by outside money, which saved them even more!

So you can see that the institute saved a whole bunch of money by having grad students.

Answer (score 9):

An answer already given is a good one, but an advisor once summarized funding and degrees in a rather pithy way that bears repeating here:

> Universities want money from professional degrees, so they hope you go out into the world, become wealthy, and donate to them later, but charge you up front in case you don't
>
> Universities want prestige from research degrees, so they cover your expenses so you don't have to worry about making money and can go out in the world and become famous, but make you do menial labor for next to nothing, in case you don't

For those unfamiliar with the dichotomy:

- Professional degree are anything that leads to a specific job: MD, LL.D., MBA etc.
- Research degrees are degrees in specific subjects that don't necessarily lend themselves to any job: MA, MS, PhD etc.

Comment: I believe universities' expectations from PhD candidates are more related to their actual PhD work rather than future fame. What's more, future fame is attributed more to where you are now than to where you were before.

Answer (score 5):

The other answers nicely address the direct relationship between the university and the graduate student, and why the university might want to fund the graduate studies.  While all true, in my opinion, this largely misses the point of STEM graduate students.

At a research university, the STEM stars are the faculty, who bring in a lot of grant money.  The primary purpose of graduate students is to provide those faculty with research (and teaching) assistance.  Creating a graduate program is considered a benefit for faculty.

If graduate students are paid at below-market rates, then the faculty will  not get good students, they will not be happy, and their research (and, more importantly in the eyes of the university, their grant money) will suffer.

Answer (score 4):

If you're starting your applied math graduate studies at the University of Texas at Austin, you may well end up working at the [Center for Subsurface Modeling](http://csm.ices.utexas.edu/), a research group devoted to the mathematical study of underground fluids. You'll be doing this in a state that gets an enormous amount of [revenue](http://www.texastransparency.org/State_Finance/Budget_Finance/Reports/Revenue_by_Source/revenue_hist.php) from underground fluids, and a state where lawns and cattle and people depend on underground fluids to [survive](http://res.dallasnews.com/interactives/drought/waterdriller/). Many Americans depend on underground fluids, which is why the US National Science Foundation just gave the Center for Subsurface Modeling [$1.5 million](http://csm.ices.utexas.edu/dr-wheeler-and-collaborators-receive-1-5-million-nsf-grant/) to keep studying them. Many Ph.D. students worked very hard to help bring in that $1.5 million grant. You will work very hard to help bring in the next one.

In general, universities pay for graduate work in the sciences because they think graduate work in the sciences pays off. Sometimes the [payoff](https://www.nsfgrfp.org/fellows/profiles/sergey_brin) is a huge jackpot that everyone notices. Sometimes the [payoff](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=800116.803773) is a huge jackpot that few will ever [understand](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1481024). Sometimes the [payoff](http://www.lifehacker.com.au/2015/12/the-rear-admiral-who-invented-the-compiler-amazing-grace-hopper/) builds up slowly over fifty years and quietly remakes the world. Sometimes the [big payoff](https://www.quantamagazine.org/20160330-sphere-packing-solved-in-higher-dimensions/) looks too surreal to be worth hundreds of thousands of dollars of actual money, but there are other [little payoffs](https://arxiv.org/abs/1009.4407) with more [practical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_design) benefits. Sometimes the [payoff](https://www.quantamagazine.org/20151208-four-mathematicians/) is so deep that it's hard to guess what benefits it might bring.

I don't know why universities and their funding agencies seem to value graduate work in the sciences more than graduate work in the humanities. After all, humanities graduate students also go on to [bring down](https://psmag.com/the-organ-detective-a-career-spent-uncovering-a-hidden-global-market-in-human-flesh-b10832c31ccd#.pzp1lo7m1) international crime rings, [serve](http://www.atthelectern.com/recent-article-assesses-mariano-florentino-cuellars-judicial-outlook-and-temperament/) on state supreme courts, [organize](https://kinginstitute.stanford.edu/king-papers/documents/table-contents-and-headnote-comparison-conceptions-god-thinking-paul-tillich) major social movements, and [change](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_hooks) the way we see the world. Maybe it's because the payoffs of graduate research are less immediate in the humanities: I can't point to any humanities Ph.D. theses that led directly to practical applications, the way I can in the sciences. (Of course, the humanities are far outside my area of expertise.) Maybe it's because the government and industry stakeholders who drive investment in sciences graduate studies are more wary of the [returns](http://www.sciencemag.org/news/2016/04/alexandra-elbakyan-founded-sci-hub-thwart-journal-paywalls) humanities graduate studies can bring.

Whatever the cause of the funding gap between sciences and humanities, you can at least assure your family that applied math Ph.D.s are widely considered a solid investment. Applied mathematicians often work on pretty practical [problems](http://blogs.siam.org/category/research/), and they sometimes collaborate directly with industry [partners](http://csm.ices.utexas.edu/industrial-affiliates/). Your university will be spending 50 grand a year on you because they convinced some funding agencies that your training and research will be worth it, and their industrial affiliates will be laughing all the way to the gas station.

Comment: *I don't know why universities and their funding agencies seem to value graduate work in the sciences more than graduate work in the humanities.* Possibly because of [what they have to compete with](http://www.payscale.com/college-salary-report/majors-that-pay-you-back/bachelors) to attract talented students who might otherwise enter the workforce with a bachelors degree: a student with a brand-new BS in STEM can more easily get a high-paying job than the student who just earned a BA in English Literature.

Comment: The things you listed as payoffs for graduate work in the humanity are all issues that aren't commerically exploitable. As a result there are no companies lobbying for public spending on it.

Answer (score 0):

Many universities consider research (as much or even more than teaching) to be their core business. PhD students drive research. They help academics to remain research-productive and before the end of their PhDs, they are productive researchers in their own right. By publishing papers and helping academics to win research funding, they help to draw extra funding into the university and also help to keep the university's research ranking, and hence national and international reputation, high. This in turn helps to increase the numebr and quality of undergraduate students who want to study at the university, which also brings in money. Universities may also receive direct government funding for graduating PhD students.

Answer (score -3):

Because that number of "$50k per year" is imaginary.  Anyone they are charging "$50k per year" is essentially paying for **your** education and being rewarded with a place at the university.

I know others had similar answers/comments, but they were too long and complicated.